# If $c\in\mathbb C$ is an algebraic number then for every $k\in\mathbb Z$, $kc$ is also algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

> Prove that if $c\in\mathbb C$ is an algebric number then for every $k\in\mathbb Z$, $kc$ is also algebric

So if $c$ is happened to be a rational it's trivial.

How to solve the case of $c\in\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Hint: what does it mean that $c$ is algebraic?

Comment: @Magdiragdag, I know that it means that there's a minimal polynomial such that $p(x) = (x-c)q(x)$

Comment: What is the definition _exactly_? ($p$ has an important property).

Comment: @Magdiragdag, $p(x)$ is monic and has rational coefficients

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $k=0$ the problem is trivial, and if $k \neq 0$, since $c$ is a solution to a rational coefficient polynomial, say $P(x)$, we have that $kc$ is a solution to $P\left( \dfrac{x}{k} \right)$, another rational coefficient polynomial (note $k$ is an integer). So $kc$ is a solution to a rational coefficient polynomial.

Comment: Oh of course, I had that in mind actually . Thanks!

Comment: Said another way, if $c$ is a root of the rational polynomial $P(z)=\sum a_nz^n, a_n\in\mathbb Q$, then for any $k$, $kc$ is a root of the rational polynomial $P_k(z)=\sum b_nz^n$ where $b_n=a_n/k^n\in\mathbb Q$

Comment: @Moya Yes. That's another way of saying it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the definition of algebraic directly. Given a polynomial $p$ with rational coefficients such that $p(c) = 0$, and an integer $k$, can you make a polynomial $q$ such that $q(kc) = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Some authors define algebraic numbers as the roots of polynomials with *integer* coefficients (although of course, if we allow *rational* coefficients, the definition is equivalent).

If $p\in\Bbb Z[X]$, $\deg p=n$ and $p(c)=0$ then $q(X)=k^np(X/k)\in\Bbb Z[X]$ and $q(ck)=0$.